# .NET Core Web App Url Rewrite to new domain not working

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using the following code in Startup.cs to try and redirect an old domain to a new one (rather than doing this at my DNS provider), but no matter what variations I try, it doesn't seem to trigger. Any help appreciated!

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
.AddRedirect("https://old.mydomain.com$", "https://new.mydomain.com/$1", 301)
```

Comment: Have you also added `app.UseRewriter(options)` inside your `Configure` method?

Comment: Yes. I have other redirect and rewrite rules in place and they work fine. This rule is the first one I have specified. Funnily if I try  running it locally like .AddRedirect(@"^https://localhost$", "https://new.mydomain.com/$1", 301) it actually works fine. Im deploying it to Azure App Services, so not sure if that helps as to why it doesn't work? I don't think I need to use the IIS style XML format right?

Comment: Having an IIS styled XML format ideally does the job, but does this have anything to do with the outbound traffic? Check this out - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.0#unsupported-features

Comment: If a user visits the old domain, it is just a redirect to the new domain, so I don't think that is outbound?

Comment: By definition, any traffic going out of the network is outbound. That's what is leading me to that thought

Comment: Ok I think I get it. So the built in really middleware can only handle internal redirects and rewrites. I can confirm using the IIS XML file does work so I guess thats the solution for now!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219385/discussion-between-raj-and-sai-gummaluri).